# Generate list of traceable and planar graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks

Is there any way to tell Mathematica to generate a list of graphs that are both [traceable](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TraceableGraph.html) and [planar](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PlanarGraph.html)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check [`GraphData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphData.html).

Get a list of names with this command:

```
Intersection[
 GraphData["Planar"],
 GraphData["Traceable"]
]
```

Apply `GraphData` to a name to get the graph.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks!